# Laravel route, include all URI's after path

Tags: php, laravel

While this appears to be a simple task, I'm stuck. Trying to construct a route for the path /admin that routes everything from /admin to any combination of path after /admin.

This route works if the path is anything like /admin/login or /admin/error but does not catch just /admin.

```
Route::domain(env('APP_URL', 'app.firstaccessdata.com'))->get('/admin/{any}', function() {
    return view('admin');
})->where('any', '.*')->name('main.admin');
```

This works for just /admin but if anything is appended to the path after /admin, will not catch.

```
Route::domain(env('APP_URL', 'app.firstaccessdata.com'))->get('/admin', function() {
    return view('admin');
})->name('main.admin');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said, extremely simple - just needed to make the {any} parameter optional by adding a question mark. Now this route captures both /admin and /admin/anything/after/it

```
Route::domain(env('APP_URL', 'app.firstaccessdata.com'))->get('/admin/{any?}', function() {
    return view('admin');
})->where('any', '.*')->name('main.admin');
```